# CIBloom makes image smaller

Tags: cgimage, ciimage

I'm using CIBloom to blur some text inside a `CGImage`, but what is happening is the CIBloom filter seems to be ***making my image very slightly smaller***.

The effect is worse when the filter kernel is made bigger.  I kind of expected this but I need a way to turn it off, or a formula to resize the image so that each letter is exactly the same size that it originally was.  I'm leaving margins on my source image on purpose.

Before CIBloom filter:

[image: a]

After CIBloom filter:

[image]

The code that blurs the filter:

```
CGImageRef cgImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( tex->cgContext ) ;

CIImage *cii = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageRef] ;

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBloom"] ; //CIGaussianBlur

[filter setValue:cii forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1f] forKey:@"inputIntensity"];

// Large radius makes result EVEN SMALLER:
//[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CIImage *ciResult = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CGImageRef cgIRes = [ciContext createCGImage:ciResult fromRect:[ciResult extent]];

//Clear old tex
tex->clearBacking( 0, 0, 0, 1 ) ;

// Drop CIImage result into texture raw data
CGContextDrawImage( tex->cgContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, tex->w, tex->h), cgIRes ) ;
```

I like the `CIBloom` filter, but I need the results to be **the same size as my original image**, not downsampled.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the extra space added to the image for the default kernel size of 10 is 21x28.

[image]

For K=10, the resultant image has 21 px added to each side, and 28 px added to the top and bottom. Keeping in mind the backing is 768x1024 px, it looks like the scale up produces an image that is 810x1080.

Playing around with this, I came up with the following

```
CGContextDrawImage( tex->cgContext, CGRectMake(-30, -36, tex->w+2*30, tex->h+2*36), cgIRes ) ;
```

This seems very approximate (there must be a formula for this) and introduces some distortion, but it works to make the image nearly the same size that it originally was, without introducing borders.

[image]

Comment: dude thank you, i've been looking for a solution to this for a while now

Comment: I didn't end up using it.  Instead I wrote my own bloom filter based on [Philip Rideout](http://prideout.net/archive/bloom/)'s example code

Answer (score 0):

The bloom effect changes the position and size of your original image. So you need to edit them back.
In your case you change the following code line:

```
CGImageRef cgIRes = [ciContext createCGImage:ciResult fromRect:[ciResult extent]];
```

into

```
CGImageRef cgIRes = [ciContext createCGImage:ciResult fromRect:[cii extent]];
```

Hope it helps you